# Как убрать контур линии на canvas JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

есть обычный canvas(холст), на нём можно рисовать линии. После, я скачиваю холст через canvas.toDataURL("image/png"). Линии рисуются нормально (через stroke()), но оставляют контур, который я не могу никак убрать. Сам контур можно увидеть только при большом увеличении. Как убрать контур?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты вообще в курсе, чем растровая графика отличается от векторной?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет...

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как быть?

Comment: Ну используй svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Спасибо вам